# use rails fixture object in another fixture file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I would like to use an object within a fixtures-file that was instantiated within another fixtures file.
Something like the following (which is not working):

```
monitor_france:
  objecttype_id: 2
  name1: i-france-1
  name2: <%= monitors(:big_brother).name %>
```

In case you wonder why I try weird things like this: I'm dealing with a legacy database...

Answer (score 7):

This is how you could query the database:

```
<%= User.find(ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify('john')).email %>
```

[Documentation to FixtureSet](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html)

Comment: Note this relies on fixtures users fixture being loaded before this fixture. Unfortunately there's no official way to specify fixture load order. You can determine the ID without loading because it's based on a hash, so it's easy to setup standard ActiveRecord associations, but fetching items with ActiveRecord relies on the objects already being in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
name2: <%= Fixtures.identify(:big_brother).name %>
```

or when you're calling a association that already exist in the model you can just do

model1.rb

```
has_one :name2
```

then in the fixture you can just do

```
name2: big_brother
```

Check out the fixtures class:
http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: <%= Fixtures.identify(:big_brother).name %> --> That won't work. identify() returns an integer (the object's id, not the object itself).